# GPS Distance Calculation

Tags: gps, haversine

I want to calculate the distance between two GPS locations, each with a latitute value and a longitude value. The calculations should be accurate for short-distance results. eg. < 300m. If I use Google Earth (see coord in my code) , the distance is ~136m.
If I use the solution provided by article: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html (the haversine formula) the result is nothing near that.

used code:

```
public void GpsCalc(){
    double d = getDistance(51.342299,4.371359, 51.342490,4.371997); 
    Log.e("GpsCalc", String.valueOf(d));
}

public static double getDistance(double lat1, double lng1, double lat2, double lng2){
    double R = 6371; // earth’s radius (mean radius = 6,371km)
    double dLat =  Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);

    double dLon =  Math.toRadians(lng2-lng1); 
    double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
               Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) * 
               Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2); 
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
    double dr1 = R * c;//in radians      

    Log.e("getDistance-dr1", String.valueOf(dr1));

    return dr1;
}
```

I'm sure it should be some minor change, but i can't see it.

Comment: Google gives a lot of answers for `android gps distance`. For example: http://www.tutorials-android.com/learn/How_to_calculate_the_distance_between_two_GPS_coordinates.rhtml

Comment: You mentioned that you expect < 300m, but that's exactly what you're getting...? When I put in your coordinates in to that page or run it through your code, I end up with 0.049km = 49m. Is your problem that you're expecting something even closer to Google Earth's?

Comment: kabuko, that's exactly my problem. GoogleEarth returns 136m which is more realistic. I don't mind small deviations as <10m, but 136 and 49 are too big of a difference.

Comment: Peter, thank you. I will look at the tutorial and get back to you.

Comment: Peter, i've implemented the code but when i use the gps coordinates as given in my code, it returns a value of 3108.398468379165m. So i'm getting pretty much stuck here. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I have also had trouble with the haversine formula on that page. I know it's not precisely an answer to your question, but I had more success with the law of cosines formula, which gives the same results as Google Earth. In case it helps, it looked like this:

```
public double getDistance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
    double latA = Math.toRadians(lat1);
    double lonA = Math.toRadians(lon1);
    double latB = Math.toRadians(lat2);
    double lonB = Math.toRadians(lon2);
    double cosAng = (Math.cos(latA) * Math.cos(latB) * Math.cos(lonB-lonA)) +
                    (Math.sin(latA) * Math.sin(latB));
    double ang = Math.acos(cosAng);
    double dist = ang * EARTH_RADIUS;
    return dist;
}
```

**EDIT:**

I tried your coordinates in Google Maps and Google Earth and in my code, and I'm getting 49m for all of them. Maybe there was never a problem?
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Steve, your code basicly returns the same 49m. Are you able to test is with the coordinates i have used? Can't imagine Google Earth is wrong.

Comment: When i enter my coordinate values in http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html the calculation is correct. So there must be a minor difference in detail between upper functions and the theoretical function from the site.

Comment: FWIW, I'm also getting the 49m result at http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html.

Comment: Hi Steve. This screenshot is helping me a lot! I notices there is a difference in our coordinate notation. Your notation of the gps points are like float-notations which are separated by a comma. When i enter coordinates while adding a placemark i type  51°34'22.99"N and 4°37'13.59"E. This results in a different place on earth. So i think that the function calculates the right distance but that my coordinate-formatting is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but two more options

1. Using Apple Corelocation (49.2733 meters)

   ```
   CLLocation *currentLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:_posGPSCurrent.latitude longitude:_posGPSCurrent.longitude];

   CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:_posGPSTarget.latitude longitude:_posGPSTarget.longitude];

   // in kilometers
   CLLocationDistance distance =[currentLocation distanceFromLocation:location]/1000;
   ```
2. Manual calculation (49.1393 meters)

Include Math library

```
#include <math.h>

// distance in Kilometers (Haversine)

-(double)distanceFromGPSlat1:(double)tlat1 lon2:(double)tlon1 lat2:(double)tlat2 lon2:(double)tlon2
{
double distance = ((acos(sin(tlat1*M_PI/180)*sin(tlat2*M_PI/180)+cos(tlat1*M_PI/180)*cos(tlat2*M_PI/180)*cos((tlon1-tlon2)*M_PI/180))*180/M_PI)*60*1.1515*1.609344);

return distance;
}
```

Perhaps I prefer the second method (Manual calculation).